# Good way to plot a variable between conditions with multiple measurements

Tags: r, data-visualization, lme4-nlme

I've a frame containing

> Participant----Condition----Duration
>   Participant1,One,2000
>   Participant1,One,2780
>   Participant1,One,200
>   Participant2,Two,2000
>   Participant2,Two,2340
>   Participant2,Two,2120
>   Participant2,Two,2420
>   Participant2,Two,2990
>   Participant3,One,2120

and so on... basically for each participant there are multiple measures of the duration. In order to compare the duration vs the condition i'm using

> lme(Duration~Condition,random=~1|Participant)
>   and 
>   plot.lme(model,Condition~fitted(.))

to have an idea of the model.

I'm wondering if there is a way to plot the real data, in a summary style like plotmeans. I mean I can use plotmeans with the relation is 1:1 between participant and measure, otherwise the mean is "pulled" by the participnat with more entries. Is there something similar for repeated measures? Grand mean maybe?

Thanks

Comment: How many participants? How many conditions? How many measures per participant? Does each participant get only one condition (as in your sample?)

Comment: Let's say 18 participants, two conditions (between experiment),not fixed,yes

Comment: want something like this ?  library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(data= df,aes(x=Duration,y=Condition))+geom_point()+facet_grid(~Participant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a smaller example:

```
Duration <- rnorm(20)
Part <- c(1,1,1,2,2,
          2,3,3,4,4,
          5,5,6,6,6,
          7,7,7,8,8)
Cond <- c(rep(1,10), rep(2,10))

plot(Part, Duration, type = 'n')
points(jitter(Part), jitter(Duration), col = Cond)
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this way it's hard to see if there is a possible "clustering" of the data between the conditions...

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I was looking for a way to get a better expression of the mean in presence of repetition, but i think i'm off-road...Thank again for the solution

Comment: You could add a line for the mean.